# Zooming and translate in as3 AIR Android

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, zooming, translate

I am developing an android app with Adobe Flash cs6 and actionscript3. I have multiple moviclips at various locations on stage. Now I need to add a zoom feature that will zoom all movieclips as one movieclip. I cannot combine all movieclips together into one movieclip. My zoom feature works but it does not translate the movieclips to a new position. (Meaning they zoom at their original positions only) How can I accomplish this? Following is my zooming code :

```
/* ZOOM FEATURE */
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

zoomer.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM , onZoom); 
function onZoom (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
mc1.scaleX *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2; 
mc1.scaleY *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2; 

mc2.scaleX *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2; 
mc2.scaleY *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2;

mc3.scaleX *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2; 
mc3.scaleY *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2;

}
```

Comment: why can't you make the mcs children of a parent mc / sprite?

Comment: Are you still looking for another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest code I've written, but it should do the trick.  `scaleInPlace()` accepts 4 arguments, 2 required, two optional:

- `obj`: the display object you want to scale
- `scaleFactor`: just as it sounds, how big/small do you want it?
- `fromX`: the X coordinate where you want to scale from.  Left, middle, right? If omitted, it operates from the middle of the compiled stage size.
- `fromY`: same as the previous, but for top, middle, bottom.

This will preserve your DisplayList hierarchy while allowing you to scale to your heart's desire.  If you had a lot of objects to scale, I'd probably parent all of them to the `container` first, and then run the scale and reparenting operations.  While it works, this is the reason I feel it's not the "cleanest" solution.  In my own classes, I've written a purely mathematical solution that doesn't include adding/removing `DisplayObjects`, but it's fairly tied up in my own classes I couldn't pull it out here and have it work.

Cheers!

---

```
// Let's scale myObject to 50% of its original size.
scaleInPlace(myObject, 0.5);

function scaleInPlace(obj:DisplayObject, scaleFactor:Number, fromX:Number = NaN, fromY:Number = NaN):void {
    // If no coordinates from where to scale the image are provided, start at the middle of the screen
    if (isNaN(fromX)) { fromX = loaderInfo.width/2; }
    if (isNaN(fromY)) { fromY = loaderInfo.height/2; }

    var father:DisplayObjectContainer = obj.parent;
    var rect:Rectangle; // Coordinates for tracking our object
    var index:int = getChildIndex(obj) // Where this object should go when we put it back

    // Create the container
    var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
    father.addChild(container);

    // Place the origin of the scale operation
    container.x = fromX;
    container.y = fromY;

    // Get the coordinates of our object relative to our container
    rect = obj.getRect(container);

    // Parent and move into place
    container.addChild(obj);
    obj.x = rect.x;
    obj.y = rect.y;

    // Scale
    container.scaleX = container.scaleY = scaleFactor;

    // Get the coordinates and size of our scaled object relative to our father
    rect = obj.getRect(father);

    // Cleanup the display list
    father.addChildAt(obj, index);
    father.removeChild(container)

    // Apply the new coordinates and size
    obj.x = rect.x;
    obj.y = rect.y;
    obj.width = rect.width;
    obj.height = rect.height;
}
```